# Why Increasing the number of cores in my spark job is not reducing the time taken even if the partition is evenly distributed?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark job which just reads files from a parquet folder path and writes to another folder path

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Read Write Parquet EFS") \
    .getOrCreate()
input_folder_path = "/home/ubuntu/efs-spark/10M-32part/input"
output_folder_path = "/home/ubuntu/efs-spark/10M-32part/output"
df = spark.read.parquet(input_folder_path)
df = spark.write.parquet(output_folder_path)
```

Input data: 10M rows,

CPU: 16
Time taken: 10 sec
partitions: 16

CPU: 32
Time taken: 10 sec
partitions: 32

The only task that was split and processed was the write operation and it took 5 seconds even if it was 16 or 32 core, I also confirmed if the partition is evenly distributed  during both 16(625000 rows each) and 32(312500 rows each) partitions.

My question is in that case since each partition size is less in 32 partitions with 32 cpu the write should be faster say 2.5 secs if 16 partitions with 16 CPU, but both are taking ~5 secs.

I also confirmed that the time taken by each task in both execution is 4000 to 5000 ms there is no difference between the tasks in both cases

What am I missing why the 32 CPU process didn't complete in 2.5 secs.

I was expecting the writing task to complete in 2.5 sec with 32 CPU since it took 5 secs to complete the job with 16 CPU, but there was no difference and the 32 CPU job also took 5 secs.

Comment: i suggest you check the executor metrics in spark UI. it'd tell you how the job is distributed across your two tests.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are on a unique machine. Moreover, you're just copying data from one directory to another on the same disk. In that case, the limiting factor is not the computing power but the disk I/O speed.

**So increasing the number of cores will not make your job faster because in your case you're limited by your disk I/O speed**